# Is there an overview of possible order types of fragments of first-order arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

I know, that there aren't many results on order types of arithmetic fragments. E.g. there are some basic results which one can find in texts of Kaye and Bovykin. But does anyone know, if there is something like an overview of the possible order types of (weak) arithmetic fragments like $Q$, $IOpen$, $I\Delta_0$ or $I\Sigma_1$ as far as they have been discovered until today?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in "The metamathematics of first-order logic" by Hajek and Pudlak: [http://www.amazon.com/Metamathematics-First-Order-Arithmetic-Perspectives-Mathematical/dp/354063648X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/354063648X).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Well, thanks! The books of Kaye, Hajek/Pudlak and Kossak/Schmerl are just in front of me including Bovykin's PhD Thesis. While Hajek/Pudlak discuss several fragments they are not quite interested in order types. Kaye discusses order types e.g. in chapter 6 but for nonstandard models of first-order arithmetic only and not for fragments as far as I understand. And when reading Kossak/Schmerl I always get a headache ;-)

Comment: There was no downvote by me.

Comment: Have you tried contacting this guy: http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~jjohanns/fragments.html ?

Comment: @Nagase: Thanks for that hint. I've contacted him.

Comment: @Nagase: Jan Johannsen kindly has sent me his paper. Thx again!

Comment: @HeywoodFloyd - Nice; is there in it an overview of the type you were asking about?